# Are all quasi-regular points on Polish spaces generic points?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, measure-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $X$ be a Polish space and $T\colon X\to X$ be a continuous map. We say that a point $x\in X$ is *quasi-regular* if for every bounded continous function $\varphi\colon X\to\mathbb{R}$ the sequence $A_n\varphi(x)$ of Birkhoff averages converges as $n\to\infty$, where $$A_n\varphi(x)=\frac1n\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \varphi(T^j(x)).$$

Setting $$L_x(\varphi)=\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n\varphi(x)$$ we obtain a bounded linear functional on the space $\mathcal{C}_b(X)$ of bounded continous functions $\varphi\colon X\to\mathbb{R}$. Clearly, $L_x(\varphi)=L_x(\varphi\circ T)$, but does $L_x$ have to be given by $$L_x(\varphi)=\int_X\varphi\,\text{d}\mu$$ for some $T$-invariant Borel probability measure $\mu$ on $X$?

### Comments

Clearly, the answer is yes if we assume that $X$ is compact (by the Riesz theorem). Furthermore, if $\hat{X}$ is any compactification of $X$, the $L_x$ must be given by some Borel probability measure $\hat{\mu}$ on $\hat{X}$, but since it may be impossible to extend $T$ to $\hat{X}$ we cannot claim that $\hat{\mu}$ is $T$-invariant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$A_n \varphi (x) = \int_X \varphi \mathrm{d} \mu_n$ for a Borel probability measure $\mu_n$, in fact a measure with finite support
$\{ T^j(x) \mid j=0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$.
By the assumption about the point $x$, the sequence of $\mu_n$ is weakly Cauchy, where "weakly" refers to the duality between the space $M_\sigma(X)$ of finite Borel measures on $X$ and the space $C_b(X)$.
The space $M_\sigma(X)$ is weakly sequentially complete (Bogachev, ``Measure Theory'', Theorem 8.7.1).
Therefore there is a measure $\mu\in M_\sigma(X)$ such that
$\int_X\varphi\mathrm{d}\mu=\lim_n\int_X\varphi\mathrm{d}\mu_n$
for every $\varphi\in C_b(X)$.
Then $L_x (\varphi) = \int_X \varphi \mathrm{d} \mu$.
The measure $\mu$ is $T$-invariant because
$L_x(\varphi)=L_x(\varphi\circ T)$ for every $\varphi\in C_b(X)$.

Comment: To use completeness, it is necessary to specify a metric, and prove that a sequence is Cauchy in that metric.

Comment: @YuvalPeres Here, _weak sequential completeness_ means that every fundamental sequence converges, where a sequence $\mu_n$ is said to be _fundamental_ if for every bounded continuous function $f$, the sequence $\int f\,\mathrm{d}\mu_n$ is fundamental ($=$ Cauchy). [Bogachev, Sections 8.1 and 8.7]

Comment: I have added more words to the answer, to spell out the steps of the argument.